# tailwind css is not working in my threejs website

Tags: html, css, three.js, tailwind-css

I am using threejs website with webpack  and to style my website I am using Tailwind CSS and I tried to configure it and this not working in my browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>Globe animation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-1/2">
        <h1>Globe</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="w-1/2" id="canvasContainer">
      <!-- Threejs canvas globe -->
      <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: css file]

[image: tailwind config file]

[image: post cofig css file]

Comment: "not working" isn't a great explanation. You should mention what you are trying to achieve as an end result

Comment: I was trying to `flex` two divs aside and its not working when I install the tailwind but it working in cdn